# Next software release

Tags: releases

Afternoon Community, 
I was wondering if anyone knows the date, or approx date, of the next software update. Also if anyone has some good sources for pooling this kind of information that they could link me too it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot guys and good luck in the red sea. HODL

Comment: What software are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean next hardfork. The current timeframe puts it somewhere in October/November, an exact day isn't finalized yet. http://weekinethereum.com is a pretty good source that does a weekly list of updates in the ecosystem, and a hardfork date decision would definitely be on there.